# Why doesn't drawtext show on transparent bg?

Tags: ffmpeg

This command outputs white (25% opacity) text on a black bg:

```
ffmpeg -i greensolid.avi -filter_complex "color=black:s=1920x1080[tmp];[tmp]drawtext=text='mystring':fontsize=25:fontcolor=white@0.25:x=386:y=161'[text];[0:v][text]overlay=0:0" output.mp4
```

This command only outputs a green video (no text).

```
ffmpeg -i greensolid.avi -filter_complex "color=black@0:s=1920x1080[tmp];[tmp]drawtext=text='mystring':fontsize=25:fontcolor=white@0.25:x=386:y=161'[text];[0:v][text]overlay=0:0" output.mp4
```

In theory the second command would output white (25% opacity) text on a green background.

Comment: The encoders `libx264` and `mpeg4` do not support alpha channel. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I've edited my question to add some clarity to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: What LN said. Older versions (< Oct 2016) did not output text on transparent bg, but we don't know if that's the issue here since you're encoding to a codec that will drop the alpha channel. Output to MOV and with codec `-c:v png` or `-c:v qtrle`. Also, add `:format=rgb` to the overlay filter.

Comment: @Mulvya, thank you. I rendered to a PNG sequence, and the text is not showing on the transparent background. I am using 2.8.8, so I will try updating.